# Cans are all sealed, but I forgot to boil the closed jars - should I boil them now?

Tags: boiling, canning

I am relatively new at canning.  Last night I made a batch of peach butter using a trusted recipe that I have made and canned before.  I sterilized my jars and lids, ladled the boiling peach butter into each jar, and put the lids and bands on.  Within a couple of hours, all of the "buttons" popped in indicating to me that they have sealed.

However, what I realized this morning was that I never actually boiled the closed jars.  Since they are already sealed, should I boil them again?  (By the time I get home, the jars will have been sealed and kept at room temperature for about 20 hours).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40097/67 (although, no idea on the 20hr thing ... especially as peaches are less acidic than tomatoes)

Answer (score 2):

I know the inversion method doesn't involve a water bath, you simply fill the jars, put the lid and band on them, and turn them upside down.  There's question on how safe that is.  (I know you didn't do the inversion method, but it's close even if by accident.)

I know marmalades can take up to two weeks to firm up and if they don't by then, it's suggested to reprocess them.  At this point, I would say you would be safe to reprocess them.  I wouldn't put what you have directly into a water bath though.  I would pour the contents back into a pot and bring to a boil.  Meanwhile, wash the jars and bands and use new lids.  Then fill the clean (hot) jars and put into a water bath.

Comment: Also worth mentioning -- if you store them at room temp, you should keep the bands loose so the lids can potentially pop up if there's microbial activity ... and never eat from a jar that's had the lid pop on you.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/16677/67